# What are the criteria for earning ranked team rewards?

Tags: league-of-legends

My friends and I have a team, there are some of us who rarely get to play, and some of us that play frequently. Is there a percentage or threshold of games that an individual player needs to participate in to earn end of season rewards?

Comment: If I can remember correctly, it is 5 wins on the team in the particular queue for those rewards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Riot posted the following in the [Season 3 Rewards FAQ](http://beta.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/check-out-season-3-rewards-faq)

> For ranked 5v5 or 3v3 team queues, you’ll earn the rewards based on
>   your team’s highest tier, but keep in mind that you have to have
>   played at least five games with the team and participated in 30% or
>   more of the team’s total games to qualify for rewards.

Comment: It's about a week later, and it seems they've changed it from 30% participation to 10 won games.

Answer (score 3):

On September 12th, 2012, Riot announced [the revised criteria](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/news/season-2-rewards-and-ratings-changes) to receive Season 2 rewards, which were handed out on November 6th, 2012.

In order to receive rewards for a ranked team, you must have met one of these two conditions:

1. You joined the team before September 12th, 2012, or
2. You *win* 5 games with the team. This must be done in each queue. That is, to get 3v3 rewards, you need to win five 3v3 games -- 5v5 games don't count.

It's noteworthy that there have only been 2 seasons, and that the criteria for rewards has changed between them. Note also that condition #1 seems to only be because the revision was announced within that month.

This information should thus be considered volatile, and you'll have to wait for the Season 3 rewards announcement to be sure of anything.